# Photoshop Technique for Such Effect - How Was It Done?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics-editing

If you take a look at [the DevDays logo](http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/), or the [Graphic Design](http://events.carsonified.com/fowd/2009/london/mp3s/mike-kus-4/videos) [presentation](http://carsonified.com/blog/features/graphic-design-the-forgotten-web-standard/) from FOWA, there are **certain letters in the logos that are extended upwards or in some direction**, such as the V and Y pictured below. I wish to **attempt to mimic this effect in Photoshop**. I have watched the [presentation design video](http://carsonified.com/blog/features/graphic-design-the-forgotten-web-standard/), but, as it's so fast, I wasn't really able to tell how the designer did it. Specifically, I would like to find out the **easiest approach for accomplishing something like the extended letters in the second logo below**. I'm currently thinking of somehow utilizing the **clone patch** tool, but I'm not certain how to obtain the desired result.

[image: DevDays Logo]

[image: Graphic Design presentation logo]

**UPDATE**: From the first answer, I have an idea - would rasterizing the text and then transforming it work as an alternative?

**UPDATE #2:** Thanks so much for answering my question! However, I just realized that I'm also curious in another thing about the Graphic Design logo: **how was the word "graphic" separated so that "design" could be put in between?**

Comment: It's pretty easy to draw a rectangle on a computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is no work for Photoshop. In Illustrator or Freehand, just choose "Convert type to outlines" and stretch the anchor points of the letter vectors up and down. It's vector work anyway. After you finish the design, you can rasterize it for web use, for print it should remain vectorized.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, having watched the video, what the designer is doing, is selecting only a part of the letters, the part to extend/repeat, then he is copying it, and pasting it several times, to make such effect, nothing more sophisticated ;)

Since these are basic geometrical shapes, I'm guessing that even without copying several times, stretching the copied/pasted area is working too.